# python - how do I find two desired integer values in a variable?

Tags: python, numbers

I'm in the process of learning how to code in Python and have been doing numerous tasks to help solidify info.

I had 1 issue - I am creating code that will take the date (dd/mm/yyyy) and then the program will validate the data (i.e checking if there are errors in the field and if so, naming the error type; if no errors are found, the user is told the input was correct) - just some data validation practise.

Where I'm getting stuck is just assigning the variables - I have typed and tested the day and year correctly but I cant manage to get the 4th and 5th integer of the variable *date* for the month variable.

Here is my code that I am first producing to make sure the integers I will be working with are correct:

```
date = input("Please enter the date in format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
valid_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/-'

#defines where to locate day in user input
dayDate = str(date)[:2]
# could also be written as dayDate = str(date)[:-8]

#defines where to locate month in user input
def month(date):
    return date[(len(date)//2)]
finalMonth = month(date)

#defines where to locate year in user input
yearDate = str(date)[-4:]


print(yearDate)
print(finalMonth)
print(dayDate)
```

- From this code, the variables *yearDate* and *dayDate* present me with the values I want but the finalMonth is where i'm getting stuck. I've looked all over Google but can't seem to find the solution. If you do know how to solve my issue, I would really appreciate it if you could send the proper way to go about this and why you did what, as I am still kind of a newb in Python :)
- I know the error is the function I've created for finding the month values, but that's precisely where I need help.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Sorry! I am new to Stack overflow so I didn't know.

so the code:

```
def month(date):
    return date[(len(date)//2)]
finalMonth = month(date)

print(finalMonth)
```

returns the output '/' but what I am trying to get is for example you input '26/01/2021' and the variable finalMonth will give '01' - this code produces '/'. I am not sure what method should be used to get the month value.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Give me the code to solve this” is not a Stack Overflow issue.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: It also seems that you need to repeat your materials on string processing.  You keep converting a string to a string, and you perform unexplained slice operations where `split` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I have made an edit! Apologies for the mistake - I am new to Stack Overflow

Comment: I'll wait for the MRE and your post-research code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `split()` to create a list from input as below

```
date = input("Please enter the date in format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
valid_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/-'

#defines where to locate day in user input
day, month, year = date.split("/")
print( day, month, year )
```

Comment: I really like this! It's removed the '/' but then how would I make the month a separate variable?

Comment: I just edited the answer, now you have three variables `day`, `month`, `year`.

Comment: thank you so much! This is perfect for what I am trying to do. I wasn't aware of the function split() before so this is really insightful.  Again, thank you so much Shoaib!

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer to your error you were having is change
`date[(len(date)//2)]` to `date[3:5]`

After your clarification, I put together an example showing how you can handle error checking. :)

```
import datetime as dt

# the -> is to hint at the type of variable this function will return, this is not needed, but good practice 
def get_date_from_user() -> dt.datetime:
    # This will keep looping until correct gets changed to True
    correct = False
    while correct is False:
        user_input = input("Please enter the date in format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
        try:
            # This part can be done in a lot of ways, I did it this way to demonstrate a condensed way and type conversions 
            date = dt.datetime(int(user_input[-4:]), int(user_input[:2]), int(user_input[3:5]))
            correct = True  # If the datetime was made successfully, set the loop to TRUE to escape
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
    return date

date = get_date_from_user()
print(f'Day: {date.day} Month: {date.month} Year: {date.year}')
```

For handling dates though I highly recommend checking out [Pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/). With it you could do something like this:

```
import pendulum

date = pendulum.parse(input("Please enter the date in format dd/mm/yyyy: "))

dayDate = date.day
finalMonth = date.month
yearDate = date.year
```

It will throw an error if it cant parse what they typed in as well. If you wrap it in a Try and Except cause you can catch that too like below:
[Python error handeling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

```
import pendulum

try:
    date = pendulum.parse(input("Please enter the date in format dd/mm/yyyy: "))
except ValueError as err:
    print(err)

dayDate = date.day
finalMonth = date.month
yearDate = date.year
```

Comment: Hi there AbnormalGeek! Thanks for the reply! Say the input is '26/01/2021', I would like the user to be presented with a message that says 'The input was correct' but if the user inputs, for example, '30/02/2021', then an error is produced and the type of mistake they made is also produced; or if they type '29/13/2021' is input, another error is given saying that there are only 12 months. I think the library you have suggested to me will be really helpful so I really appreciate this help! Will definitely try this out!

Comment: Ahhhh, just a second and ill update my answer with some good tips for you :)

Comment: Thank you for this! It's so nice to find out new ways I could of coded something that makes my workflow more efficient. I have tried this and it definitely works! :) Thank you again!